The probability that a randomly selected order 3 tensor has rank 3 is neither 0 nor 1.
The claim in the title was one I remember reading in a paper a few months ago, that I have since not been able to find. If I remember correctly, the authors hadn't proven this, but had run some simulations that seemed to show that a random $k \times k \times k$ tensor was 70% of the time rank 3 and 30% of the time rank 2. Or something to that effect.
This is surprising because the set of matrices of rank $k < n$ are of Lebesgue measure zero in $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$. The case of tensors of order 3 was clearly not so simple.
Does anyone know where this, or a similar claim, might have been made?

This is for $2 \times 2 \times 2$ tensors over $\mathbb{R}$, they have (real) tensor rank $2$ with probability $\frac{\pi}{4}$, and $3$ — with probability $1-\frac{\pi}{4}$. The existence of two typical ranks in this case was discovered by Kruskal, and the exact probability was computed by G.Bergqvist in the paper "Exact probabilities for typical ranks of 2 × 2 × 2 and 3 × 3 × 2 tensors", Linear Algebra Appl. 438:663-667 (2013), doi:10.1016/j.laa.2011.02.041.
